# Make a simple Python dictionary generator 

Tags: python, dictionary, generator

Here is a sample code basically doing an iteration.

```
>>> d = {'lol': {'12': '3',  '35':''}, 'w': {'12': '3', '35':''}}

>>> def iteritems(s):
...     keys = s.keys()
...     for key in keys:
...             yield key, s[key]
... 
>>> for k, v in iteritems(d):
...     print k, v
... 
w {'12': '3', '35': ''}
lol {'12': '3', '35': ''}
```

This is a valid generator. But the generator `iteritems` have to call `s.keys()` to cache all the keys in the dictionary. If the dictionary is large (over 100 items), that's not memory efficient.

But since dictionary is not an ordered structure, I assume that getting that list of keys is a must.

One may argue: the number of keys is far less than the number of items counting keys and values.

Any suggestion? Or better way (and of course I need to support nested iteation but that's another thing).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`.iterkeys()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iterkeys) in python 2.x; in python 3.x, [`.keys()` is a view](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) and not a new list. In python 2.7, you can also use the [`viewkeys()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) to get the same thing.

There is an equivalent [`.iteritems()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems), making your utility method redundant. :-) The same remarks apply here for python 3.x and 2.7, see the documentation supplied.

Comment: Ah. SO it's built-in and I used to think `keys` is a list. Big mistake. Wait but is `iterkeys` a generator - or is it just a plain iterator that must put the entire dictionary into memory?

Comment: @CppLearner: `iterkeys()` is an *iterator*. Generator functions also produce iterators, so in a sense, the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually confused. In the docs, `.items` is a copy. But the `iteritems` is an iterator and I think that's just a iterator built on top of `items`. So wouldn't it just be another plain iterator? The doc does not specify whether it's a plain iterator with `next()` method or an iterator with generator benefit (such as the yield statement's presence)?

Comment: @CppLearner: No, `iteritems()` iterates over the underlying dict, while `items()` creates a new list and returns that.

Comment: @CppLearner: A generator is a way to produce an iterator. The `iteritems()` method is in that sense a generator.

Answer (score 3):

You're reinventing the wheel, to avoid making an intermediate list in Python 2.x just use:

```
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    print k, v
```

In Python 3.x use:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)
```

because the `.items()` method in that version returns an iterable [view](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=items#dictionary-view-objects) object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way of using a generator to yield key/value pairs:

```py
my_dictionary = {
    'foo': [
        1, 2, 3
    ],
    'bar': [
        4, 5, 5
    ]
}

key_values = ((key, value) for key, value in my_dictionary.items())
for key, value in key_values:
    print(key, value)

# foo [1, 2, 3]
# bar [4, 5, 6]
```